# Tree Decomposition Construction with Balanced Separations: Why 2/3?

Tags: graphs, parameterized-complexity

I am working through the book "Parameterized Algorithms" [https://www.mimuw.edu.pl/~malcin/book/parameterized-algorithms.pdf](https://www.mimuw.edu.pl/%7Emalcin/book/parameterized-algorithms.pdf) and at the chapter about tree decomposition I am trying to understand the choice of using 2/3 separations instead of 1/2 separators.
It has also been stated in the exercise 7.33 that there would be a problem but I can't find it. I'd be very grateful for a hint

Thanks

Comment: The correct question is not why 2/3, but rather why balanced separations rather than separators. The 2/3 is probably optimal for balanced separations – balanced separations closer to 1/2 probably don't always exist.

Comment: @mark-regev Did you make any progress on this problem?